# Creating slope map in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hydrology, slope

I want o create one slope map for my model but I have one big problem.
I have contours lines and mass points and I create a DEM using topo to raster but if I want to create a slope map from that DEM I take a wrong slope map.

Look my image:

[image]

The yellow lines in the red frame are wrong,that is my contours lines I think so why show me that problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make a [terrain](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005v0000001p000000) from your contours and mass points then [terrain to raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q90000002t000000) with the *natural neighbours* method, this will give a smoother raster - not necessarily more accurate but won't jump as much.

Comment: I tried what you said but did not have any different the same errors not chenge .

Comment: When you built the terrain did you use contours as type 'contour'? if you use them as hard line you will get the same problem.

Comment: yes i use that..and i use soft line

Comment: So do the sudden slopes match with contours? Is their elevation set correctly (z height or elevation attribute)? Contours are a model, usually cartographic, and don't align well with exact changes in elevation. You can sometimes get better results if you remove points close to contours.